# Selecting a div from prototype response Magento

Tags: ajax, magento, html, prototypejs

Hello i am using Prototype javascript library in Magento.

I am getting an ajax response and everything is working fine.

The response is saved in the response variable.

```
var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
```

What i want is to fetch a div and its content from the response variable. I am totally confused on how to do it.

I want to get the div and its content and replace it with the current div and its content.

I know how to do it by `$('div').update('content')` but i am not able to fetch the exact div the content within the div.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var container = new Element("div", {}).update(responseText); // this way you get a valid Prototype Element that you can easily query
// performs your query on the Prototype Element
// NOTE: remember to not include the root "div" when attaching your response to the html page
```

Hopefully I answered your question. If not, please add a sample of code of what you are trying to accomplish!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I have a variable which has the whole html page in it. The variable name is "response".
and i want to fetch the content associated with the "div" named "top-cart" by $('top-cart').update(ResponseForTopCart);